# How to make android-emulator pop out in android-studio

Tags: linux, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using flutter for the first time on linux (Ubuntu). When I was on Windows, the emulator of my android device poped out like this: [image: normal way]

but now it looks like this: (it is in a tab or something in the android-studio)
[image: how it looks in my case = wrong]

how can I make it, that it looks like the first image? (that the emulated phone pops out like in the first picture)

Greetings and thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On android studio upper bar

File->settings->tools->emulator->
then check or uncheck -launch in tool window

Answer (score 0):

File -> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator
And disable "Launch in a tool window"